# On conflict, update if json value is different in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, psycopg2

I would like to update the '*info*' column in the "*raw_data*" table, if it differs from existing.

Where "*info*" is **JSON** datatype.

For example, if the "*info*" data exist, DO NOTHING, otherwise UPDATE.

### Code and attempts:

If I use the following code:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()

postgres_insert_query = 
"""
INSERT INTO raw_data (Timestamp, IMIE, info) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)
ON CONFLICT (Timestamp)
DO UPDATE SET
info = EXCLUDED.info 
WHERE raw_data.info IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.info;"""

record_to_insert = (int(timestamp), int(imei), json_file)
cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)
connection.commit()
```

### Error:

Then I would receive the following error:

> psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is
>   aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

### **Sample/Pseudo code:**

*DO NOTHING Case:*

```
If Current "info" = {someData: 'ON'} 
Existing "info" = {someData: 'ON'} 
Then Do Nothing
```

*UPDATING Case:*

```
If Current "info" = {someData: 'OFFFFFFFFFFF'} 
Existing "info" = {someData: 'ON'} 

UPDATE the "info"
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Thank you for your response, as suggested I have added the sample data and desired.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you are right I have added the error message.

Comment: The error "*current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block*" indicates that something else went wrong **before** you ran that last statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't compare JSON values with `=` or `<>` (which is what `is distinct from` uses in the background). If you want to compare the **complete** JSON value you have to change the data type of that column to `jsonb`, e.g. the following works just fine.

Using this sample table:

```
create table raw_data ("timestamp" timestamp primary key, imie text, info jsonb);
```

You can then run this:

```
INSERT INTO raw_data ("timestamp", imie, info) 
VALUES (timestamp '2019-07-22 00:00:00', '1234', '{"x": 1, "someData": "on"}')
ON CONFLICT ("timestamp")
DO UPDATE 
  SET info = EXCLUDED.info 
WHERE raw_data.info IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.info;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/IOYXB82745

But it looks like you don't actually want to compare the complete JSON value, but only one key. Then you can do the following, which also works with `json`:

```
INSERT INTO raw_data ("timestamp", imie, info) 
VALUES (timestamp '2019-07-22 00:00:00', '1234', '{"x": 1, "someData": "on"}')
ON CONFLICT ("timestamp")
DO UPDATE 
  SET info = EXCLUDED.info 
WHERE raw_data.info ->> 'someData' IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.info ->> 'someData';
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/VML98935

Comment: oh, rextester. ty.